# Kali linux desktop is unresponsive

Tags: kali-linux, xfce4

My desktop is unresponsive, after i login to my account the wallpaper is stuck in the default wallpaper that kali uses until it loads the one you have chosen, programs icons, the trash icon and directory icons don't load and i can't right click on the desktop.The panel is working normally and all the programs work normally too.

I updated the system and restarted my laptop, nothing changed.I also tried to restart xfce4-panel process using the `killall` command but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try signing on with a Terminal session and then run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
 and see if that restores normal operating.

Comment: You mean boot on a terminal session or just open a terminal and type the commands?

Comment: If you can open a terminal session on start then yes type that command.   Try Ctrl - Alt - F1 or F2 on boot.

Comment: Then just reboot from the terminal?

Comment: If you can get to Terminal, run the command string I posted, allow it to complete and then, yes, restart and see.

Comment: No desktop is still not responsive

Comment: I have fixed my own Kali virtual machines this way but if that does not work, you may have to reinstall Kali.

Comment: Ok I will wait for another answer and then will reinstall

Answer (score -1):

I will keep my original response below my resolution.

Okay so I have a resolution, it's one of these two things because before I restarted my computer, I did these two things.

I'll show line by line my commands

```
 1. sudo su
```

*Password prompt [password]*

```
 2. passwd
```

*Prompt to set new root password [password]*
*Prompt to re enter new password [password]*

```
 3. usermod -U root
```

*Unlocking the root account*

```
 4. login root
```

*Check to make sure root account has been successfully unlocked*
*Prompt for root password you just set [password]*
*If successful you will be logged into root*

**just to state the obvious, I am pretty certain that just creating a new user with usermod would work just the same, however this is what I did, so who knows, maybe usermod wont work for some odd reason**

**The only other thing I did was when I restarted my computer, I turned off my second monitor. Doubtful this is what did it but who knows**

And then restart computer and log in with new credentials.

------- start of original response ---------

My issue exactly, this is what I did leading up to event > nothing out of the ordinary, basic web browsing, only change made was to allocate memory to huge pages

sudo sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=102400

I also placed:
vm.nr_hugepages = 102400
Inside /etc/sysctl.conf followed by a restart. Prior to that it has been a couple days before my last restart however I don't recall doing anything that would cause any system issues.

This is what happens:
When I turn my computer on it will boot up just fine, the speed is normal, even the splash page to put in my user and pass is fine, however once I sign in, immediate drag, system slows down, nothing is responsive, and no icons on my desktop populate besides my bar with the start button,date,login drop-down cpu usage/memory monitor(also non responsive sitting frozen at 10% area on both) which all as well is non responsive.

What I've done and can do:
Mouse moves and keyboard is responsive so I can move my mouse around for hours, but that gets boring and I can press alt+f1 - f6 and from there everything works well except when changes are being made, ie apt-get update something works fine, downloads everything, however after that process is done and the final part of making the changes from that operation takes for ever, even apt update works fine however the final part where it updates what just got updated takes forever. I literally walk away.

Lastly:
If I dare go back to alt+f7, all icons like the internet, cpu and memory usage that is in the cluster usually on the right side of that bar besides the time, disappears, and getting back to alt+f1 is now a process that involves me walking away.

Hope that detail helps us getting this resolved.

Also I have restarted plenty of times from the alt+f1 screen. This is what always happens now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).